# how to get values from two different tables which do not have any connection

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I need to get

1. question
2. ans1
3. ans2
4. ans3
5. ans4
   from `question` table and
6. answerAry
   from `answer` table **TOGETHER**.

Here is how my tables look like:
`question`
    qid question ans1 ans2 ans3 ans4
`answer`
    ans_id answerAry

*What I want is:*
question, ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4, and answerAry WHERE ans_id = :id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select q.*,
       (select a.answerAry from answer a where a.ans_id = :id) as answerAry
from question q;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon Linoff. You make my day :3.